# Copy numpy array from one (2-D) to another (3-D)

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

I tried to copy one array, says A (2-D) to another array, says B (3-D) which have following shape

A is m * n array and B is m * n * p array

I tried the following code but it is very slow, like 1 sec/frame

```
for r in range (0, h):
    for c in range (0, w):
        x = random.randint(0, 20)
        B[r, c, x] = A[r, c]
```

I also read some websites about fancy indexing but I still don't know how to apply it in mine.

Comment: Do you actually want the third index to be random and vary from element to element, or is this just an illustration?

Comment: Also, please tidy up your notation. You have `m`, `n`, `p`, `h`, `w` and `20`.

Comment: @Marciano it would be faster to do: `´B[..., x] = A.copy()`

Comment: @SaulloCastro: There is no need to call `copy` in that case.

Comment: @NPE Yes, I wanted the 3rd dimension to be randomly assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a solution using array indices.  `M`,`N`,`P` are each `(m,n)` index arrays, specifying the m*n elements of `B` that will receive data from `A`.

```
def indexing(A, p):
    m,n = A.shape
    B = np.zeros((m,n,p), dtype=int)
    P = np.random.randint(0, p, (m,n))
    M, N = np.indices(A.shape)
    B[M,N,P] = A
    return B
```

For comparision, the original loop, and the solution using shuffle

```
def looping(A, p):
    m, n = A.shape
    B = np.zeros((m,n,p), dtype=int)
    for r in range (m):
        for c in range (n):
            x = np.random.randint(0, p)
            B[r, c, x] = A[r, c]
    return B

def shuffling(A, p):
    m, n = A.shape
    B = np.zeros((m,n,p), dtype=int)
    B[:,:,0] = A
    map(np.random.shuffle, B.reshape(m*n,p))
    return B
```

for m,n,p = 1000,1000,20, timings are:

```
looping:    1.16 s
shuffling: 10 s
indexing:     271 ms
```

for small m,n,  looping is fastest.  My indexing solution takes more time to setup, but the actual assignment is fast.  The shuffling solution has as many iterations as the original.

---

The `M`,`N` arrays don't have to be full.  They can be column and row arrays, respectively

```
M = np.arange(m)[:,None]
N = np.arange(n)[None,:]
```

or

```
M,N = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
```

This shaves off some time, more so for small test cases than a large one.

---

A repeatable version:

```
def indexing(A, p, B=None):
    m, n = A.shape
    if B is None:
        B = np.zeros((m,n,p), dtype=int)
    for r in range (m):
        for c in range (n):
            x = np.random.randint(0, p)
            B[r, c, x] = A[r, c]
    return B
indexing(A,p,indexing(A,p))
```

If `A` isn't the same size as the 1st 2 dim of `B` the index ranges will have to be changed.  `A` doesn't have to be a 2D array either:

```
B[[0,0,2],[1,1,0],[3,4,5]] = [10,11,12]
```

Comment: It works, thanks! By the way, my array B will be updated continually but only some values in B are selected to be updated while the others are left as their old values. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: All the more reason to use the 'indexing' solution.  Just move the `B` initialization outside the function.

Comment: I already moved B initialization outside the function and my function just only update the value inside B in the random indices. But my point is that I also want some pixels to be updated while others don't, randomly. For example, I have another variable and at each pixel, I'll random this variable. If the value of this variable is 1, that pixel will be updated. Otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that h=m, w=n and x=p, this should give you the same as you have in your example:

```
B[:,:,0]=A
map(np.random.shuffle, B.reshape(h*w,p))
```

Note also, I'm assuming the answer to NPE's question in comments is 'yes'

Comment: In my timings, this is slower than the original loop (5-10x).  The `map` hides a loop of `h*w` times.